# Translate not working on Firefox, please, does anyone know why?

Tags: css, debugging, cross-platform, css-animations

I'm been trying to make an animation work cross platform and I recently gave up on ie, but i can't understand why none of the instances where i use translate work in firefox, can anyone show me if I'm doing something wrong please? Forever gratefull.

Here's my code up to know:

```
span.glow-left{position: absolute; bottom: 50px; left: -10px; display: block;    width:40px; height: 80px; background: url(../img/glow-left.png) no-repeat; 

-webkit-animation:glowleft 2s linear infinite;
-moz-animation:glowleft 2s linear infinite;
animation:glowleft 2s linear infinite;
-webkit-animation-delay: 1s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
animation-delay: 1s;
-webkit-animation-name: glowleft;
animation-name: glowleft;}

@keyframes glowleft { 
    1%{ -moz-transform:  translatey(-20px);opacity:0.5;}
    2%{ -moz-transform:  translatey(-20px);opacity:1;}
    13% { -moz-transform:  translatey(-150px); opacity: 1 }
    40% { -moz-transform:  translatey(-340px); opacity:0.5;} 
    50% { -moz-transform:  translatey(-340px); opacity:0;} 
    100% { -moz-transform:  translatey(-340px); opacity: 0; } 
}

@-webkit-keyframes glowleft { 
    1%{ -webkit-transform:  translatey(-20px);opacity:0.5;}
    2%{ -webkit-transform:  translatey(-20px);opacity:1;}
    13% { -webkit-transform:  translatey(-150px); opacity: 1 }
    40% { -webkit-transform:  translatey(-340px); opacity:0.5;} 
    50% { -webkit-transform:  translatey(-340px); opacity:0;} 
    100% { -webkit-transform:  translatey(-340px); opacity: 0; } 
}

@keyframes glowleft { 
    1%{ -webkit-transform:  translatey(-20px);opacity:0.5;}
    2%{ -webkit-transform:  translatey(-20px);opacity:1;}
    13% { -webkit-transform:  translatey(-150px); opacity: 1 }
    40% { -webkit-transform:  translatey(-340px); opacity:0.5;} 
    50% { -webkit-transform:  translatey(-340px); opacity:0;} 
    100% { -webkit-transform:  translatey(-340px); opacity: 0; } 
}
```

I know it's a mess, but please help.

Comment: Shouldn't the first `@keyframes glowleft` be `@-moz-keyframes glowleft`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You messed up teh keyframes...and you are missing the "@-moz-keyframes glowleft" section:

try this:

```
@-moz-keyframes glowleft { 
1%{ -moz-transform:  translatey(-20px);opacity:0.5;}
2%{ -moz-transform:  translatey(-20px);opacity:1;}
13% { -moz-transform:  translatey(-150px); opacity: 1 }
40% { -moz-transform:  translatey(-340px); opacity:0.5;} 
50% { -moz-transform:  translatey(-340px); opacity:0;} 
100% { -moz-transform:  translatey(-340px); opacity: 0; } 
}
@-webkit-keyframes glowleft { 
1%{ -webkit-transform:  translatey(-20px);opacity:0.5;}
2%{ -webkit-transform:  translatey(-20px);opacity:1;}
13% { -webkit-transform:  translatey(-150px); opacity: 1 }
40% { -webkit-transform:  translatey(-340px); opacity:0.5;} 
50% { -webkit-transform:  translatey(-340px); opacity:0;} 
100% { -webkit-transform:  translatey(-340px); opacity: 0; } 
}
@keyframes glowleft { 
1%{ transform:  translatey(-20px);opacity:0.5;}
2%{ transform:  translatey(-20px);opacity:1;}
13% { transform:  translatey(-150px); opacity: 1 }
40% { transform:  translatey(-340px); opacity:0.5;} 
50% { transform:  translatey(-340px); opacity:0;} 
100% { transform:  translatey(-340px); opacity: 0; } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you guys, I knew something was wrong, just didn't know what. I tried this way, and it worked, but before that I also managed to find out that firefox animations should have -moz specific keyframes, so i tried it with @keyframes var{-moz-transform:...}} and it worked as well. Thanks for the help.